# Is the Redis cluster installed in k8s have less performance compared to installed standalone?

Tags: performance, kubernetes, redis

I am going to install redis cluster for the use for my applications,
I was planning install them by using prepared helm chart,

But there's a saying goes:

> Redis installed in k8s will have less performance compared to standalone installations, because of shared hardware resources (CPU, memories...)

Is that true?

Comment: You will be sharing resources with the other services running on the same node. You can however assign your redis pods to specific nodes, and prevent anything else to run on those nodes to avoid sharing resources.

Comment: well, yes !! If you compare the services provided by cloud providers for these then they are better and more stable, as they have tested these along multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by Burak in the comments you can choose to have a dedicated node(s) only for the Redis pods in order to avoid resource sharing with other services.

Also it is worth to mention that Redis performance is tied to the underlying VM specifications. Redis is single-threaded so a fast CPUs with large caches would perform better. Multi-cores do not directly affects performance. If your workload is relatively small (objects are less than 10 KB), memory is not as critical in order to optimize the performance.

Finally, you can use the [redis-benchmark](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) in order to test the performance yourself. There are plenty of examples to check out. Or use other tools like [memtier_benchmark](https://github.com/RedisLabs/memtier_benchmark#memtier_benchmark) or [Redis Memory Analyzer](https://github.com/gamenet/redis-memory-analyzer#redis-memory-analyzer).

Comment: thanks for the tools you suggested. Good to know about them!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Redis Installed as a kubernetes pod(container) gives less performance compared to a standalone installations. I have experienced it first hand. Tried so many optimisations to no avail.

Finally, I tried giving a dedicated node for redis pod and it did improve the performance (latency in my case).

I performed benchmarking in both cases(dedicated node vs no dedicated node for redis pod). I have turned of persistence, topology is standalone ( only master and no workers, no sentinel).

Also remember that there is something called intrinsic latency: https://redis.io/docs/management/optimization/latency/#latency-baseline

> There is a kind of latency that is inherently part of the environment where you run Redis, that is the latency provided by your operating system kernel and, if you are using virtualization, by the hypervisor you are using. 
>  
> While this latency can't be removed it is important to study it because it is the baseline, or in other words, you won't be able to achieve a Redis latency that is better than the latency that every process running in your environment will experience because of the kernel or hypervisor implementation or setup.

So even if you give a dedicated node, it is still less performant than a redis server directly on a physical machine.